# jquery check values in form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two inputs where I am checking to make sure that they are not empty before the form submits.

My issue is that it only validates #from_date. Is the issue that .val will only check the last id in the list?

```
    $('#submitDates').click(function () {
      // Get the fields you want to validate
      var name = $("#to_date, #from_date");

      // Check if field is empty or not
      if (name.val()=='') {
        alert ('Please Select Dates')
        return false;
      } ;

     }); 
    });
```

Comment: When you call `.val()` on a collection of multiple elements, it returns the value of the first element in the collection. This is in the first sentence of the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any specific reason you're hooking on `.click` and not `.submit`?

You can iterate through the selected elements and check for a violating element using [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
var found = false;
$("#to_date, #from_date").each(function(i,name){
      // Check if field is empty or not
      if (!found && $(name).val()=='') {
        alert ('Please Select Dates')
        found = true;
      } ;
});
return !found;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it just submits the form even when both are empty. There is a small syntax error also on the last }

Comment: @KeithPower I fixed the syntax error, the point was to get you on your way I didn't test the script. I updated the answer (using .val() works on jQuery objects, each runs on the underlying DOM elements, I added a $() around the element).

Answer (score 0):

In your example `var name = $("#to_date, #from_date");` is giving you a collection of two inputs and by doing `if (name.val()=='')` jQuery is checking only the first element in the collection, so it's not working. You may try this

```
$('#submitDates').click(function () {
    var name = $("#to_date, #from_date");
    if ( name[0].value == '' || name[1].value == '' ) {
        alert ('Please Select Dates');
        return false;
    }
});
```

In the above example `name[0].value` refers to the first element and `name[1].value` refers to the second element. If you want to use jQuery's `val()` method then you can use it like `$(name[0]).val()` and `$(name[1]).val()`.

Also you should consider to use `submit` event of the form instead of button's click event.